# How to visit elasticsearch in docker in another docker?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I deploy elasticsearch in docker with below command:

```
sudo docker run --name es1 -p 6200:9200 -p 6300:9300 -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" -e discovery.type=single-node -e "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.3
```

the host ip where the docker container run is hostip
the inet addr of docker0 is 172.17.0.1
docker inpect above ES container and its ip is: 172.17.0.5

I run command in host directly(step 1):

```
curl -XGET 'hostip:6200'
```

then I get result

I run command in another docker which is deployed on the same host with above ES(step 2):

```
curl -XGET 'hostip:6200'
```

nothing get and the visit will timeout

I run command in another docker which is deployed on the same host with above ES(step 3):

```
curl -XGET '172.17.0.1:6200'
```

nothing get and the visit will timeout

I run command in another docker which is deployed on the same host with above ES(step 4):

```
curl -XGET '172.17.0.5:9200'
```

then I get result

I run command in another host which is diff with the host above ES deployed(step 5):

```
curl -XGET 'hostip:6200'
```

then I get result

I run command in another docker which is deployed on the diff host with above ES(step 6):

```
curl -XGET 'hostip:6200'
```

then I get result

so my question is: how can I visit this ES container with hostip:6200 from another container which deployed on the same host ?

--net=host is not the choose under my condition.

Comment: I would expect either the external host IP address or the docker0 bridge address to work, and would suspect some sort of firewall setup if they don't.  Putting the two containers on the same Docker network and using the container name as a hostname (and the internal port 9200) is a better choice, though.  Looking up the container-internal IP addresses tends to lead to trouble (they change somewhat routinely; they're not reachable from other hosts).

Comment: I tried on centos and found the firewall is blocking the packages. Just try by disabling firewall. cmd   - systemctl stop firewalld . or more specifically you can open 6200 port. execute below cmds "firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=6200/tcp --permanent" and then  firewall-cmd --reload. it should work.

Comment: @RohitJindal step1, step5, step6 can tell that 6200 is open.

Comment: @Keyang Can you please try by disabling firewalld. And share the result?

Comment: @RohitJindal sorry for the delay. I tried and found it worked. surprisely.but how to manually change iptables to make it work rather than disable iptables?